# Why does Power BI give me sum of unfiltered data when data actually is filtered?

Tags: powerbi

Power BI shows wrong Sum value.

[![[![In the first picture all values correct, but when I want to sum up the orders prices by status it gives me summary of all orders (not filtered by Lead_ID)

[image]]
[image: The second picture]

Power BI does not sum properly (see pictures).
The Price_Totals shall be filtered by Lead_IDs and  Status. When I let data be not aggregated, it works fine, but when I want to sum up Prices by Status (while filted by Lead_IDs) I get completely wrong number (supposedly sum of all the orders-prices without filtering).

All tree columns are coming from tree different tables.
[![This is the presentation on how these tables are connected][image]

Comment: You may want to create a measure to CALCULATE the sum with ALL() and VALUES(). Also, what happens if you use the corresponding FK from the order table instead?

Comment: It is probably a good idea for you to read up and learn about data models in Power BI, specifically relationship types and their attributes.

Comment: Could you share your measure formulas and which table-columns are included in the visuals?